# Would this union work if char had stricter alignment requirements than int?

Tags: c, alignment, iso, unions

Recently I came across the following snippet, which is an attempt to ensure all bytes of `i` (nad no more) are accessible as individual elements of `c`:

```
union {
  int i;
  char c[sizeof(int)];
};
```

Now this seems a good idea, but I wonder if the standard allows for the case where the alignment requirements for `char` are more restrictive than that for `int`.

In other words, is it possible to have a four-byte int which is required to be aligned on a four-byte boundary with a one-byte `char` (it is one byte, by definition, see below) required to be aligned on a sixteen-byte boundary?

And would this stuff up the use of the union above?

Two things to note.

1. I'm talking specifically about what the standard allows here, not what a sane implementor/architecture would provide.
2. I'm using the term "byte" in the ISO C sense, where it's the width of a `char`, not necessarily 8 bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No type can ever have stricter alignment requirements than its size (because of how arrays work), and `sizeof(char)` is 1.

In case it's not obvious:

- `sizeof(T [N])` is `sizeof(T)*N`.
- `sizeof` is in units of `char`; all types are represented as a fixed number of bytes (`char`), that number being their size. See 6.2.6 (Representation of Types) for details.
- Given `T A[2];`, `(char *)&A[1] - (char *)&A[0]` is equal to `sizeof A[0]`.
- Therefore the alignment requirement for `T` is no greater than `sizeof(T)` (in fact it divides `sizeof(T)`)

Comment: You'll need to cite ISO to convince me on that one, R. What particular feature of arrays wouldn't work if you automatically scaled the `a[i]` and `a+i` using the alignment rather than the size?

Comment: @paxdiablo: Then this wouldn't work. `(void *) a + i * sizeof(*a)`

Comment: @sharth - That doesn't work anyway - pointer arithmetic on `void *` isn't allowed.

Comment: Whoops. I didn't realize that. gcc apparently only warns about that with pedantic. But that still should be valid if I cast to a uint8_t.

Comment: @sharth - `uint8_t` is going to be a `typedef` for `unsigned char`. Same alignment issues.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Read 6.2.6 Representation of Types. All types are represented in units of `char`. The size of an array is the number of elements times the size of the element type. Etc. etc. etc. This is all very basic.

Comment: @sharth: The type you want is `char *`, not `void *`. The standard guarantees the behavior you want for `char *`.

Comment: @pax Arrays can't have padding and must be contiguous per the standard. Therefore what R said is exactly right

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464448/ansi-c-unions-are-they-really-useful). There, I questioned the usefulness of C Unions and there are some interesting insights. The important thing is that the Standard does not ensure the alignment of the different fields at all!

EDIT: paxdiablo, just noticed you were one of the guys answering that question, so you should probably be familiar with this limitation.