# How to define NaN value in ANSI C?

Tags: c, floating-point, nan, c89

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NaN Literal in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714131/nan-literal-in-c)

I'm writing a function in ANSI C which receives two numbers as parameters. The parameters are of `int` or `float` type. The number may or may not be valid according to my filter. How do I return some value meaning failure? The return type is `float`. The first thing that come to my mind was the `NaN` abstract type. But I don't know how to represent it in ANSI C.

(sorry for my bad english. English isn't my native language)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: But it's C99

Comment: One of the answers suggested `0.0/0.0`.

Comment: There is no absolutely portable way, NaN doesn't exist in C89 and is not mandatory from C99.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NaN isn't an "abstract type".  It's a value of a floating-point datum.

If by "ANSI C" you mean standard C (which is the actual meaning of the term, in as much as it has one), include `<math.h>` and use the `NAN` macro to produce a nan, and `isnan(x)` to detect one.

If by "ANSI C" you actually mean the long-replaced C89 standard (which some people intend, even if it isn't formally correct), you can produce a NaN value with `0./0.`, and check for one with `x != x`.

Comment: You can even create a small wrapper in your code that detects if the code is not being compiled as C99 or higher and then defines the macros `NAN` and `isnan` to the ones your answer.

Comment: @Will: certainly, though I don't think that `0./0.` formally satisfies the requirements of the `NAN` macro (namely that it should be useable for static initialization); still that's probably not a worry for most users.

Comment: @StephenCanon `0. / 0.` is a constant expression, so it is OK for static initialization.

Answer (score 5):

> The question the number may not be valid according to my "filter then how do I return some value meaning failure?

Instead of comparing the number against NaN you can use this:

```
if (x != x)  // x is NaN
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can use this expression `0.f / 0.f` to produce a `float` NaN value in C89.

Comment: OP didn't ask how to check for NaN.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, you need two variables returned, one for the value, one for the failure flag.

For example you can set thing so the function will return **true** in case of normal operation. **false** in case of failure (NaN).

The variable storing the result is passed by reference as a parameter and will hold the returning value in case of success.

```
BOOL myFunction(int inInt, float inFloat, float *outResult)
{
    /*
        PROCESSING HERE
    */

    // in case of failure

    if( /* failure condition here */ )
    {
        *outResult = 0;
        return false;
    }

    *outResult = /* your result */

    return true;
}


// how to use the function

int a;
float b;
float result;
BOOL success;

success = myFunction(a, b, &result);

if(success)
{
    // do whatever with your "result"
}
else
{
    // NaN
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Have something like this

```
if(your_variable != your_variable)
{
    return 0; //catch 0 as the failure returned value
}
else
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: -1 because this answer does not explain anything, whilst containing code that would be very confusing to anyone not already in-the-know about how to use NaN and able to spot it immediately. Also because `0` may be a perfectly reasonably return value.